# Symfony2: How to translate custom error messages in form types?

Tags: forms, internationalization, symfony

I need to translate the error messages from my form type. Here is my form Type code:

```
class ReferFriendType extends AbstractType {

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $defaultSubject = "This is a default referral subject.";
    $defaultMessage = "This is a default referral message.";

    $builder->add('email1', 'email',array(
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Email 1* :',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('email2', 'email',array(
        'label' => 'Email 2 :',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('email3', 'email',array(
        'label' => 'Email 3 :',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('email4', 'email',array(
        'label' => 'Email 4 :',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('email5', 'email',array(
        'label' => 'Email 5 :',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('subject', 'text', array(
        'data' => $defaultSubject,
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Subject* :',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'large_text'),
    ));
    $builder->add('message', 'textarea', array(
        'data' => $defaultMessage,
        'required' => true,
        'label' => 'Message* :',
        'attr' => array('rows' => '5', 'cols' => '40'),
    ));

}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    $collectionConstraint = new Collection( array(
        'fields' => array(
            'email1' => array(
                new Email(),
                new NotBlank(array(
                    'message' => 'You must enter atleast one email address for a valid submission',
                )),
            ),
            'subject' => new NotBlank(),
            'message' => new NotBlank(),
        ),
        'allowExtraFields' => true,
        'allowMissingFields' => true,
    ));

    return array(
        'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint,
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'referFriend';
}
```

}

I want to translate 'You must enter atleast one email address for a valid submission' in getDefaultOptions() method into french. I have added the translation in the messages.fr.yml. But it is not getting translated. Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Validation translations go to the `validators.LANG.yml` files — not `messages.LANG.yml` ones.

Comment: I tried creating the validators.LANG.yml and adding the translations but it dint work.

Comment: does it work with custom translation keys ?
Actually I'm trying to do something like this : 
`'label' => $this->get('translator')->trans( 'create.label.startAt', array(), 'myDomain')`

Comment: @svassr, each constraint has the `message` property that you can set to whatever custom key you want.

Comment: How will this work for a `FormError` that is added via an `EventListener` in `FormType->buildForm()`? Creating the validators.<lang>.yml and adding an error via `new FormError('form.msg_filetype')` does not work. In symfony, is the translation done before creating the FormError?

Answer (score 3):

The replacements are not set in the validation.yml file but by the Validator.

validators.en.yml

```
noFirstnameMinLimit: Please provide at least {{ limit }} characters
```

validation.yml

```
Acm\AddressBundle\Entity\Address:
    properties:
        firstname:
            - Length:
                min: 3 
                minMessage: "noFirstnameMinLimit"
```

This works for me with Symfony 2.4

Comment: is there any list of all available placeholders a la `{{ limit }}`, `{{compared_value}}`, `{{value}}` and so on ?

Comment: The available placeholders are generally documented on the page describing a particular constraint e.g. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html

The list of constraints is here 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages).

Comment: That's very clear but in my case i am adding the validations in my form type.

Answer (score 1):

It`s easy, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages
And set default_locale in /app/config/config.yml or play with $this->get('request')->setLocale('ru');