# Symfony 2.2: How to translate form validation tooltips

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form which I built with the following type of codes:

```
class FormRegister extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
          ->add('login', 'email', array('label' => 'Login', 'required' => true))
          ->add('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password', 'required' => true));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'form_register';
    }   
}
```

The tooltips are displayed upon local validation on the form. However, I would like to customize these tooltip texts (And I would like to have them in French). Anybody can help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
          ->add('login', 'email', array('label' => 'Login', 'required' => true, 'oninvalid'=>"setCustomValidity(*yourMessageHere*)"))
          ->add('password', 'password', array('label' => 'Password', 'required' => true));
    }
```

or use the related translation file `validators.fr.yml` (maybe you have to create it)
Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395535/symfony2-how-to-translate-custom-error-messages-in-form-types)